# TortoiseSvn suddenly raises "OPTIONS SSL handshake failed: SSL error: sslv3 alert illegal parameter" on Windows 7

Tags: ssl, svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn

A client of mine has trouble with TortoiseSVN. It was working fine till now. She did her last commit on Thursday Feb. 23. 2013 But now she gets the following error:

```
OPTIONS SSL handshake failed: SSL error: sslv3 alert illegal parameter
```

She cannot access the Repository anymore. No update, no checkout, no log, etc.

It is difficult to locate the problem. It shows up with tsvn 1.7.4 and 1.7.11

- She **cannot** use tsvn with the ProjectRepository
- She **cannot** use svn commandline client (http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download) with the ProjectRepository
- She **can** use tsvn  with a PlaygroundRepository on another Server
- She **can** access ProjectRepository with IE and with Firefox
- She **can** access ProjectRepository with SmartSvn
- I **can** use tsvn in their network with the ProjectServer from my macbook with parallels.

I entirely uninstalled/reinstalled tsvn -no success
I deleted %appdata%\Roaming\Subversion -no success

As an act of desperation, I installed smartsvn which makes her work again, but this cannot be the solution.

It must be the combination of tsvn,  her machine and the ProjectRepository/Server. Her Machine works with PlaygroundRepository on another server.

Any Idea is highly welcome. In paticular due to the fact that it worked last week with tsvn 1.7.4.

So the only thing which might have changes is some updates on the windows box.

Comment: We are despareately searching for a solution. We tried lots of things (change the authentification, turned off SSL3 ... nothing helps).

In the meantime, the problem came up on two more computers. on win7 32 bit as well as an XP box.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the installation of [MS012-006](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/security/bulletin/ms12-006) on the client. That hot fix broke a lot of things. Roll it back and see if connects are successful.

Comment: The hotfix is from mid 2012. As it worked until Feb 23 it can hardly be the root cause. Nevertheless, I could not find that hotfix on her machine.